# Can I fly out of Ireland to my home (India), having entered Ireland via the UK on a UK/Irish visa programme?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am planning to visit Ireland and would be applying for a UK short stay visa, I am planning to book flight tickets in such a way that I will satisfy the conditions specified by the UK/Irish visa scheme for Indians(I will first enter the UK and then travel to Ireland, the same day).

But the return ticket to home is from Dublin directly and I want to know if there is any rule that specifically states that I cannot fly back home from Ireland, without visiting the UK again?

Answer (score 4):

When you entered under the British Irish Visa Scheme you can exit the Common Travel Area  via either country you wish. There is only an entry restriction, that you must enter via the country which issued the visa.

From the [BIVS Information Sheet](https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassychina/visas/BIVS-information-note-EN.pdf) distributed by Ireland:

> Will I be able to travel home or to another country directly from either Ireland or the UK?
>
> Yes, direct travel out of the Common Travel Area either to your home country or a third country is allowed from either jurisdiction.